# Sharing Tables between Azure Mobile Service and Azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I want to create a website and a windows 8 app that share the same database. I followed this tutorial to create the website https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/ and I used the Azure Management Portal to create my mobile service.

Though each of them work perfectly, I cannot get the tables I publish through the web application to show up in my mobile service. And when I connect in my JS app using

```
var mobileService = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient(
 "url",
 "secret"
 );
```

the tables don't exist.

How can I share these tables between the two services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the Azure Mobile Services creates its tables under it's own schema (the service name). you have to move your existing tables to this schema and you have to add them in the Azure Mobile Services Portal.

see:  [Using existing database with Azure Mobile Services](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/12/using-existing-database-with-azure-mobile-services/)

Comment: I tried changing the schema name before, but I wasn't naming the primary key field "id". Thanks a lot for the link!

Comment: Also, you might want to do something like this to make the website work with the new schema name: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/e276fb02-ef9b-44eb-b481-699c1c25602d

Answer (score 2):

Paul Batum, a PM on the Mobile Services team, outlines a quick solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuremobile/thread/60764eb6-17d0-4395-a887-2a793b44ce88

Chris Risner, a Developer Evangelist for Mobile Services, also provides a full walk through here: http://chrisrisner.com/Connecting-an-Existing-Database-to-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services